# RDDs and vectors in clojure

Tags: clojure, apache-spark, rdd, flambo

Given a function to filter out dates that are greater than the maximum date determined from a subset of a given dataset (RDD) and hence use the maximum date determined to check if a given vector contains a date value greater than the maximum date determined
I tried the following:

```
(defn future-rows
  "input = { :col val :qty-col val}
   :col = Date column reference"
   [ row input ]
   (let [{:keys [ col qty-col ]} input
     get-qty-max-date (-> (:rdd @scope-rdd)
                       (f/map #(if-not (or (s/blank? (get % qty-col)) (not (pos? (read-string (get % qty-col)))))
                                 (get % col) false))
                       (f/reduce #(if (pos? (compare % %2)) %1 %2)))]
(when-not (pos? (compare (get row col) get-qty-max-date)) row)))
```

Here `row` is a `vector`. The challenge I have is the `get-qty-max-date` is of type `RDD`. How do I make the comparison in the `when-not` form?

NB: The idea is the `future-rows` function is going to be used as a predicate

Given an RDD:

```
[[" " "2009/12/02"] ["4" "2005/02/08"] ["0" "2014/12/02"] ["5" "2005/08/01"] ["2" "2007/09/02"]]
```

When `future-rows` is used as a predicate, the desired output is:

```
[["4" "2005/02/08"] ["5" "2005/08/01"] ["2" "2007/09/02"]]
```

where input is `input { :col 1 :qty-col 0 }` for the above function
the maximum-date determined is `2007/09/02`. Hence dates `2009/12/02` and `2014/12/02` which are greater is removed from the data set.

If there's any other approach on how to go about doing this, I will appreciate it.

So say we have a main function that does this

```
(defn remove-rows [xctx input]
  (f/filter (:rdd xctx) #(future-rows row { :col 1 :qty-col 0 }))
```

will produce the desired output

Thanks!

Comment: @zero323 can you help me with the above? I can provide more info, if needed. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I don't understand a whole structure. If this is a row level function why do you try to access a whole `rdd`? Ignoring that what exactly has to be filtered here? I see you remove entries with blank first field and max data value. Is that it? Finally what is the class of the date? Just a string?

Comment: @zero323 -Awesome, I'll explain the problem, I'm to write predicate functions for the main filter function `remove-rows` and in this case the `future-rows` function is the predicate. In the given `RDD` get `non-zero` values for all `qty-col` associated column values in the `rdd` and extract their corresponding `date values` : so the map will return something like `[["2005/02/08"] ["2005/08/01"] ["2007/09/02"]]` the `reduce` will return the maximum date which is `2007/09/02`. So for each `row` in the `remove-row` filter, remove the row where date-value  `col 1` is greater than `2007/09/02`

Comment: @zero323 I thought of creating a scope-rdd that goes through the entire rdd to get the maximum date, and I' also thinking of trying to ensure that the date values are properly formatted as `yyyy/MM/dd` using `clj-time.core`  `parse` and `formatter` functions. :)

Comment: It would be convenient to convert the timestamp to epoch in order to do a proper sort. btw, what are you trying to achieve? and the threading macro in your function should be ->> instead of ->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```lisp
(defn not-empty-and-positive?
  [qty-col]
  (f/fn
   [row]
   (let [x (get row qty-col)]
     (not (or (s/blank? x) (neg? (read-string x)))))))


(defn get-max-date
  [col qty-col]
    (-> (:rdd @scope-rdd)
        (f/filter (not-empty-and-positive? qty-col))
        (f/map (f/fn [row] (get row col)))
        (.top 1)
        (first)))


(defn is-past?
    [col qty-col]
    (let [max-date (get-max-date col qty-col)]
      (f/fn [row] (neg? (compare (get row col) max-date)))))


(let [{:keys [ col qty-col ]} input
      not-empty-and-positive? (not-empty-and-positive? qty-col)
      is-past? (is-past? col qty-col)]
  (-> (f/filter rdd not-empty-and-positive?) (f/filter is-past? ) (f/collect)))
```